# Can I use distinctive as a synonym for sharp?

Tags: synonyms

There was a sharp rise in prices-There was a distinctive rise in prices
Is it correct?

Comment: Ouch!  That knife is distinctive!

Answer (score 1):

No.

Distinctive could potentially mean the price rise took any sort of recognized pattern (possibly indicative of some phenomena). Not just a sharp one. A scientist working on Ebola might look for distinctive rises in blood temperature but this does not imply they are large or sudden.

A possible alternative to "sharp" might be "sudden". Or the phrase "distinct rise" is quite common (meaning distinct to the values that were present before).

Comment: So are you saying 'distinct' and 'distinctive' mean different things?

Comment: @ws2 yes "recognisably different in nature" vs "characteristic of one person or thing, and so serving to distinguish it from others." From Google definition.

Comment: Compare 'There is a *distinct* difference between butter and margarine', with 'The difference between butter and margarine is distinctive'. They both mean same to me.

Comment: They don't mean the same. The first means different. The second would need to be dfferent in a way indicative of something. Distinctive serves a classification/identification role not implied by distinct.

Comment: I shall need to ponder that some more. Can you give an example of where you would use one and not the other?

Comment: @WS2 c.f. http://grammarist.com/usage/distinct-distinctive/

Comment: Yes I can see the difference between 'the distinctive voice of Bob Dylan', and 'a distinct sound that I heard in the night'. Yes, point taken. But I am still having problems with butter being distinct from margarine, and butter and margarine having a distinctive difference.

Comment: A distinct difference just means that they are readily identifiable as different. To me the "distinctive difference" is missing a follow up phrase telling you what the difference is suppose to be distinctive of.

Comment: @WS2: *The difference between butter and margarine is distinctive* would only be meaningful in a context where you have several *other* differences (between various different pairs of things), and there was some particular aspect of the *butter/margarine* distinction that made it significantly different to all the others. Perhaps because all the other differences were based on *colour*, and could thus be detected without physical contact or other "destructive" tests (such as ***tasting*** a sample of each! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes I think it has finally sunk in with me. Thanks to Martin too for his patience.